# Assign a value to a variable and use it in next line of code or access a value directly? which is more faster? In python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have this query running in my website and takes more time to execute and I'm trying to reduce the slowness.

```
name = values.get("name")
age = values.get("age")
roll = values.access("rbac")
```

And then I'm using something like this,
config = {"name": name, "age": age, "roll": roll} this "config" is updated with update query for mongodb

The question is, does creating a new variable and assign to back to dictionary causes slowness in anyway? or I can just use "name": values.get("name") instead? does it really have any impact?

Thanks in adavnce.

Comment: This is not a question to ask us: if you want to know whether it slows your program, you need to perform the appropriate timing experiments for a start.  If you're still unsure, try profiling your program to see where the slowness occurs.  If you're confused about the results you get, or how to work around the time-consuming portions, then post those results to this site or to StackExchange.CodeReview, as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) to analyse your performance issues and make decisions accordingly.

If I try the things you mentioned, I see that there is negligible difference between two methods. (Keep in mind that Python performed the statement 1M time)

```
>>> data
{'name': 'sappaa', 'place': 'stackoverflow', 'question': 'performance', 'answer': 'timeit'}

>>> timeit.timeit("config = {} ; name = data.get('name'); place = data.get('place'); config = {'name':name, 'place':place}", globals=globals())
0.291998529999546

>>> timeit.timeit("config = {} ; config = {'name':data.get('name'), 'place':data.get('place')}", globals=globals())
0.27466267199997674
>>>
```

So use any method, which looks and reads better, I would prefer populating directly via data dictionary and not put intermediate names if they are not used anywhere else.