# python3 - Which one will be faster to execute - pop in sequence or in list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

Consider the following two pieces of code for popping keys from a dict:

1. without list comprehension

```
    d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}   
    d.pop('a')
    d.pop('b')
```

2. with list comprehension

```
    d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
    [d.pop(key) for key in ['a', 'b']]
```

Which one will be faster and why?

Comment: Assuming you just want to remove the keys  - a & b - first will be faster. Why do you think second  will be faster when you are doing additional work?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/67145260/14904573 to determine & analyse the performance of small segments by using timeit.

Comment: The first will be the preferable way of doing it.. in the latter intermediate list is thrown away after it is created which is considered [`very anti-Pythonic`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5753597/4985099)

Comment: There is no need to call the `pop` method if you are going to throw away its returning value. Use `del d['a']` instead.

Comment: Why would the list comprehension ever be faster? It requires more work (creating a list). Also, just the looping requires more work, since it requires iteration, which has overhead. More importantly, though, you should be profiling this yourself.

Comment: @sushanth perhaps even more fundamentally, you shouldn't be mixing a functional, declarative construct like list-comprehensions to implement a series of side-effects, even leaving out the unnecessary list

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make it answerable without merely repeating the question itself. It is trivial to just *test* which one is faster, and the question already explains why – because the fast one is *without* and the slow one is *with* additional operations. That said, the two are not at all equivalent – if this question is not just for curiosity, consider to *shortly* outline the usecase to avoid an XY problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import timeit
code_to_test1 =  """d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}   
d.pop('a')
d.pop('b')"""
code_to_test2 =  """d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
[d.pop(key) for key in ['a', 'b']]"""
elapsed_time1 = timeit.timeit(code_to_test1, number=5000)
elapsed_time2 = timeit.timeit(code_to_test2, number=5000)
print(elapsed_time1,elapsed_time2)
```

Output(s):

```
0.0008224000000000009 0.0017937999999999982
0.000853600000000003 0.0018411999999999942
0.0008063000000000028 0.002663699999999998
```

So as you see, the first one is faster than the second code because, in the second one, you iterating in a list.

Comment: This isn't really an answer without any explanation.